# Creating dynamic content and pages for 1000's of locations

Tags: mysql, htaccess, rewrite-rules, localization

How can I generate dynamic pages on a Wordpress website from information provided in a separate MySQL database?

I have a database with Locations and I would like to have a page for each of these created dynamically. For example, I have a database entry for LOCATION1. If the location exists in the database, I would like a page such as [www.example.com/LOCATION1/](http://www.example.com/LOCATION1/) and for the content to be dynamic, using information from the database.

Comment: As it stands this might be too broad for our site - Questions should be singular and have a definitive answer, and not solicit option-based answers or plugin recommendations. You could likely break this down into several smaller questions - perhaps starting with how to generate/synchronize page content from a separate data source.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do to improve the question.